# How to print the text of the selected option choosen through 'selectByVisibleText' method in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, select, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am new to Selenium, could any one of you let me know how to print the value selected from 'selectByVisibleText' in selenium?

I have run the test on Facebook login page, drop down for Birthday.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Specify what you have done so far, along with the code you have written. Without it, your question is not making much sense

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you select the option through **selectByVisibleText()** method to print the value you need to invoke **getFirstSelectedOption()** method as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  Select month_dd = new Select(month_dropdown);
  month_dd.selectByVisibleText("Dec");
  WebElement myElem = month_dd.getFirstSelectedOption();
  System.out.println(myElem.getText());
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Dec
  PASSED: selectDDvalues

  ===============================================
      Default test
      Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
  ===============================================
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have selected the option by visible text, you can get the option as a `WebElement` and `getText()` from it.

Example:

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("some-id")));
select.selectByVisibleText("some-text");
WebElement element = select.getFirstSelectedOption();
System.out.println(element.getText());
```